# How do I get transformers' .from_pretrained("model") to consistently show download progress in a Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter, huggingface-transformers, python-venv, ipywidgets

I'm running a Jupyter Lab instance on a remote server which I access through my browser

I'm working with a notebook from a venv kernel that imports the AutoTokenizer and AutoModelForCausalLM classes from transformers, then downloads the elements for each from a model we'll call "model", using each class' .from_pretrained method.

the actual importing and downloading works fine; however, the first time I ran the cells containing `AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("model")` and `AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("model")`, a text-based download progress bar appeared in the output text. this went through each file download until the kernel crashed (for reasons that I am yet to troubleshoot, but I suspect are related to storage allocations).

when I ran the code again, everything worked the same, but the progress bars never reappeared. the same thing happened a few weeks ago when I tried this the first time with a different model and slightly different environment

What I've tried:

I've tried creating a new kernel from a new venv. I've tried restarting jupyter. neither made a difference

there was a warning that appeared underneath the transformers import that suggested I should install ipywidgets. this was there the first time when the progress bar *did* appear, and again when it didn't, but somewhere online suggested that ipywidgets and progress bars could be linked, so I imported it to the venv anyway. this unsurprisingly did not help

I've tested whether I get output at all: I do. if I enter 1+1, "2" outputs. I also still got the ipywidgets a warning a few times before I installed it

I made sure that the output is not just being collapsed. View -> Menu -> Collapse/Expand all Outputs does not make anything new appear, besides some ellipses.

I tried doing `pip install --upgrade jupyter_client`, but it basically said there's nothing further to upgrade.

I tried a browser based on a different engine (chromium instead of ff). I tried with my adblocker on and off

if I download a different model, that does seem to work, *once*, but then as soon as the kernel crashes a single time trying to download that model, it will never show them again, even when it's clearly actually downloading them

Comment: Point might be that, in general, when running `.from_pretrained()` on auto classes you'll see a progress bar for the first time only; from the second time on, tokenizers or model weights or datasets will be loaded from the cache (might be at `/root/.cache/huggingface/...`). See eg cache management on Datasets https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/cache for further reference.